# How can I create desktop ikons on remote machines to the remote programs?

Tags: windows-7

I've copypasted a application out to several machines on our network here at work, and the (god damn stupid :-)) users are complaining that they can't find it due to the lack of a desktop icon.

Is there a way I can remotely add a desktop icon for a application that is copypasted in to the file directory of the remote machine?